# Solr configuration CentOS7 VM

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7

We have installed a **CentOS-7** in a **VM** using **VirtualBox**. Also, we have set the network configuration to use a proxy in order to have internet access. In the VirtualBox Network configuration we have three enabled adapters: NAT, Bridge Adapter and Host-only networking.  So far, we know that host and guess have 2 way communication (we can ping one from the other). 
Our problem is the following: We have installed *solr* service (*version 5.1.0*) in our VM and it actually seems to run okay.

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./solr status 
Solr process 2502 running on port 8983
{
  "solr_home":"/opt/solr/server/solr/",
  "version":"5.1.0 1672403 - timpotter - 2015-04-09 10:37:54",
  "startTime":"2015-05-21T10:12:28.407Z",
  "uptime":"0 days, 0 hours, 3 minutes, 0 seconds",
  "memory":"16.5 MB (%3.4) of 490.7 MB"}
```

But whent trying to reach the service in our browser: *192.168.56.107:8983* it says that such **web page is not available because of ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT**. We have also tried to do the same with some other services such apache but the problem is still there and we don’t find the way to access to them through our internet browser. 
Does CentOS-7 VM need some extra configuration? How can we fix it so we could access to our services through *192.168.56.107:8983*?

Answer (score 1):

Centos 7 comes with firewalld installed by default. Have you check the firewall configuration:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
```

You can add your port as:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8983/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --reload
```